# Querying related table and displaying results in CMV Attributes Table?

Tags: attribute-table, configurable-map-viewer, search

I'm trying to use the new Attributes and Search widget for CMV with a relationship query without success - I keep getting a growler message saying 'Search error; Sorry an error occurred and your search could not be completed'. I've been using Fiddler to try and monitor what is happening. I can see that the query URL is generated and it all looks fine except that it is missing the 'objectIds=' string. In the Search Widget configuration I have added the following:

```
        layers: [
        {
            name: 'Multimedia links',
            expression: '', // additional where expression applied to all queries
            idProperty: 'GIS_ID',
            queryParameters: {
                type: 'relationship', // spatial, relationship, table or database
                layerID: 'adReports', // from operational layers
                sublayerID: 0,
                relationshipID: 0,
                objectIds: [1,2,3],
                outFields: ['*']
            },
```

The relationshipID value is picked up in the resulting query URL, but objectsIds isn't.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration parameter should be `objectIDs:` with a capital D which I recognize now is in consistent with the JS API.